# Optimisations in grouping data

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to group large number of keys using apache beam . I cannot use combiner due to nature of data and logic being used in group by . I am using data flow shuffler . What other optimisations can be used ? 
I mean general considerations to be made when dealing with large grouping of data .

Answer (score 3):

In general, having too many values for the same key leads to poor performance (Known as a "hot key").

One of the methods for dealing with this involve splitting up the data into multiple keys, then combining results into fewer values and then combining those results once more for the original key.

This idea is supported automatically if you use the correct option in Dataflow. This blog suggests this by using Combine.PerKey.withHotKeyFanout or Combine.Globally.withFanout. [blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/02/writing-dataflow-pipelines-with-scalability-in-mind). It also contains some other suggestions which you may find useful.

I hope the suggestion in that blog posts helps you get to a working solution :).